# Boolean algebra probability not coming out right

Tags: probability, boolean-algebra

Assuming A,B,C,D are mutually independent.

$P[(A\cup\overline{B}\cup C)\cap(A\cup C \cup \overline{D})]$

I get $(P(A) + 1 - P(B) + P(C))(P(A) + P(C) + 1 - P(D))$

But when I plug in the numbers, I get a result that's larger than $1$, which makes no sense... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you have taken a course in Boolean algebra, you might remember the result: 
$(x+y)(x+z) = x + yz$.  Similarly, we have that
$$\begin{align*}
F &= (A\cup\overline{B}\cup C)\cap(A\cup C \cup \overline{D})\\
&= ((A\cup C)\cup\overline{B})\cap((A\cup C) \cup \overline{D})\\
&= (A \cup C) \cup (\overline{B}\cap\overline{D}) = G \cup H
\end{align*}$$
where $G= A \cup C$ and $H = \overline{B}\cap\overline{D}$.  (If you have not had Boolean algebra, drawing a Venn diagram will
help you work out this equality).  Now, we can write
$$
\begin{align*}
P(F) &= P(G \cup H) = P(G) + P(H) - P(G\cap H)\\
&= P(A\cup C) + P(\overline{B}\cap\overline{D}) - P((A\cup C)\cap(\overline{B}\cap\overline{D}))
\end{align*}
$$
where

- $P(A \cup C) = P(A) + P(C) - P(A \cap C) = P(A) + P(C) - P(A)P(C)$ because 
  $A$ and $C$ are independent events,
- $P(\overline{B}\cap\overline{D}) = P(\overline{B})P(\overline{D})$ because 
  $\overline{B}$ and $\overline{D}$ are independent events,
- $P((A\cup C)\cap(\overline{B}\cap\overline{D})) = P(A\cup C)P(\overline{B}\cap\overline{D})$ because 
  $A\cup C$ and $\overline{B}\cap\overline{D}$ are independent events as Didier Piau has noted in his answer.

If you don't believe the claim of independence in the last bulleted item, note that 
$A \cup C$ is the union of the mutually exclusive events $A$ and 
$\overline{A} \cap C$ and so
$$
\begin{align*}
P((A\cup C)\cap(\overline{B}\cap\overline{D})) 
&= P((A\cup (\overline{A} \cap C))\cap(\overline{B}\cap\overline{D}))\\
&= P(A\cap\overline{B}\cap\overline{D}) +
P(\overline{A} \cap C \cap \overline{B}\cap\overline{D})\\
&= P(A)P(\overline{B})P(\overline{D}) +
P(\overline{A})P(C)P(\overline{B})P(\overline{D})\\
&= [P(A) +
P(\overline{A})P(C)]P(\overline{B})P(\overline{D})\\
&=[P(A) +
(1 - P(A))P(C)]P(\overline{B})P(\overline{D})\\
&= P(A\cup C)P(\overline{B}\cap\overline{D}) 
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Hi. No, this is my first encounter with boolean algebra, and I'm finding it much less intuitive than the algebra of reals... thanks for the info I'll read through it tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $P(X \cap Y) \neq P(X) P(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.  Here, both your $X = A \cup \bar{B} \cup C$ and your $Y = A \cup C \cup \bar{D}$ have $A\cup C$ in them -- they are not independent.

Also $P(X \cup Y) = 1 - P(\bar{X} \cap \bar{Y}) = 1 - (1-P(X)) (1-P(Y)) \neq P(X) + P(Y)$ for $X,Y$ independent.

Comment: Ok, so $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ — Then $P(A \cup \overline{B} \cup C) + P(A \cup C \cup \overline{D}) - P(A \cup \overline{B} \cup C \cup \overline{D})$ still not giving me the right result: $P(A) + P(\overline{B}) + P(C)...$ cancels out to $P(A) + P(C)$, which isn't right.

Comment: The second part of my comment has to do with the fact that $P(A \cup \bar{B} \cup C) \neq P(A) + P(\bar{B}) + P(C)$ even if $A,B,C$ are independent.